# Mobile site downsizes

Tags: html, css

I just finished making a website, and when I tried to run it on a mobile device, the whole site, and font size downsized a lot. Is that supposed to happen?

Here's a gif showing that happening:

[image]

What's the correct way to make it responsive? I tried using `em` instead of `px`, and I have the same results.

#### codepen

```css
#sample {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus porro vero minus sequi, id sed eveniet. Eius deleniti dolorem velit, maiores saepe, quos harum facilis necessitatibus placeat, sed quidem nulla.</div>
```

Comment: The font size will obviously change according to the screen size to maintain proportionality though. You can't expect a word/letter of font-size, say 24px to have the same fixed size on a 4K screen and a mobile phone now. Pixel size is different between the two so 24 pixels will obviously look bigger on a larger screen.

Comment: Have you tested this on an actual mobile device? The emulator can sometimes zoom in and out, and not be accurate (in my experience anyway)

Comment: @ovokuro Yes. I tested my website on a mobile phone, and had the same results

Comment: "Is that supposed to happen?" -- Yes, as that is the way you have coded it. The question is, what do you *want* to happen? :P

Comment: @AndrewLyndem What's the correct way of having it "regular" for both?

Comment: You want it the same size?

Comment: What do you mean by regular?

Comment: I don't want it to downsize as much. The site I made, is not legible on mobile

Comment: Have you tried using media queries?

Comment: @ovokuro Yes, but on a motorola mobile phone, I had `(max-width: 600px)`, and nothing changed. So I checked in JavaScript `window.innerWidth`, and it was something like 1024 px

Comment: Use `em` for font size and media queries. Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/why-ems/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the website to not squeeze the elements within the screen view. In other words, you want to remove responsiveness from your site so people have to side-scroll in order to view elements that extend beyond the width of the mobile screen.

To do that, remove this line from your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's at all what the OP wants.

Comment: I'm not too sure myself what she wants exactly tbh lol Will delete this if she meant something else.

Comment: Fair enough..  :)

Comment: Actually, That's exactly what I needed. lol. I didn't have that in my header section, (never knew what that was,) and when I added it, I got the desired results. Without that, it downsizes by a large extent. Do you know of anything else that I may be missing in the header section?

Comment: Regarding responsiveness, that's the only line you need on your head section. Do mark this as the right answer and upvote it if it helped you with your problem :)